# Kubernetes SetUp on Mac for Selenium Grid

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, selenium-grid

I was doing kind of PoC on how we can leverage Kubernetes capability to run Selenium Grid Automation.
I have installed Docker for MAC on my machine which comes with Kubernetes.
I have also installed kubectl, minikube, hyperkit using brew in the same sequence.
But when I do:
minikube start --vm-driver=docker/hyperkit,

It shows:

Starting local Kubernetes cluster...
Starting VM...

and VM never starts.

Do I need to do anything else here?

Followed this tutorial: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/

Comment: Hello @RISHI KHANNA First of all you've tried to use deprecated flag --vm-driver Please use [driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/start/) instead.
Second. As I understand you use hyperkit for macOS. But, could you please explain why you provide docker/hyperkit simultaneously? For hyperkit minikube cluster should be started with command: minikube start --driver=hyperkit from [Oficial documentation page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperkit/#usage)

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin I was trying to install minikube and followed some tutorials. Initially I tried with hyperkit which got failed then tried with docker. I got the solution to this issue. Basically I had to unlink minikube from hyperkit first before starting with docker..

Comment: If you found a solution for your issue, could you please provide it in Answer for other users?

Comment: I followed these steps today to make everything works:                                                       
                                                                                                                                1.brew unlink minikube
2.  brew link minikube
 3. minikube start —driver=docker 
4. minikube config set driver docker - To make docker as default driver

Comment: It would be better to provide your information as Answer, not a comment. Only answer will be indexed and other users will be able to find necessary information. Also you can get additional reputation. I encourage you to write an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution for the listed problem. Initially I tried with hyperkit which got failed then I tried with docker.
Basically I had to unlink minikube from hyperkit first before starting with docker

Followed below steps:

1. brew unlink minikube
2. brew link minikube
3. minikube start —driver=docker
4. minikube config set driver docker - To make docker as default driver